# Maxbox GL JS Popup open event not working as expected

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to use `Popup.on('close')` and `Popup.on('open')` to trigger certain functions and open event is not working as I would expect.

When the map loads at first and a polygon is clicked, neither the open or close events is triggered. I would expect the open event to work here.

When another polygon is clicked I use `Popup.remove()` to get rid of the active popup and then a new popup is created with updated data. Only the close event is triggered here. I would expect the open event to also be triggered.

When clicking the default close button, the close event works as expected.

```
map.once('moveend',function(){

    popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setDOMContent('whatevs')
        .addTo(map);

    popup.on('close',function(){
        console.log('closing popup');
    });

    popup.on('open',function(){
        console.log('opening popup');
    });

});
```

When I click on one of my polygons I have a `flyTo` method. When the `flyTo` animation is finished I see 'closing popup' printed to the console instead of 'opening popup'. When closing the popup, 'closing popup' is printed to the console which is the expected behaviour.

Am I using these events properly? If not, how can I accomplish listening to the open and close events properly?

Comment: Do you have a link which minimally demonstrates your issue?

Comment: This is for a health care related site so I can't share the link to it unfortunately. The code I posted is a simplified version of my actual code so it's the best I can do.

Comment: That's it, a trimmed down example which demonstrates the issue.